# [Excel-VBA]Getting the specif price from cell

Tags: vba, excel

For some reasons I want to calculate how much a price will be, compared to the weight of an item.

I've created two columns in excel, what I actually want is that if I input in A1 the amount of LBS, for e.x. 100, the output need to be $150,- in B1. I've tried something with a simple VBA code. IT works but, the prices changes overtime.

In column C (LBS) and D (price), I've written down the lbs and prices (in sheet 2).
For e.x.

```
LBS Price
100 150
200 300
300 450
```

I've the following code:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim kilo As Integer, result As String

kilo = Range("A1").Value

Select Case kilo
     Case Is >= 300
         result = "450 euro"
     Case Is >= 200
         result = "300 euro"
     Case Is >= 1
         result = "150 euro"
     Case Else
         result = "nvt"
End Select

Range("B1").Value = result

End Sub
```

The problem is the list is too long, it goes to 40000 LBS. Above the 40.000 LBS/Weight there comes a price of xxx per 500 lbs/Kilo

the formula is like this between 100 and 199 lbs, the price will be € 300,-
Between 200 and 299 price will be € 450,-

Does anyone have an idea? I want to result the cell, so if the weight is between 200 and 300, the output should been € 450,- cell (B4)

Thank you very much.

Comment: You're really looking either at a weight to price map - a bit like your `If` statements - or an algorithm that converts weight to price, or a combination of the two. I'm not sure how many people would fancy trying to construct the algorithm, but some might, and if they do, they'll want the full list of weight to price values - perhaps edit your post to include that now.

Comment: At the moment the algorithm looks to be `Weight / 100 * 150`, but the question is: will the algorithm hold true after 300lbs.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not too clear on your data structure here, but the following should help to move you in the right direction:

With your list of LBS | Price in Sheet 2 (columns C and D), ensuring that list is sorted in ascending order ...

```
=VLOOKUP(A1,Sheet2!C:D,2,True)
```

This formula "looks up" the value from the cell `A1` in the first column of the range `Sheet2!C:D`. Where no match is found, by using `True` as the final parameter, we treat the (ordered) list as a set of thresholds ... the last threshold which is met or exceeded will be considered the "matched" row. The third parameter `2`, means we retrieve the second within the range `Sheet2!C:D`.

You can find the Office Support page for `VLOOKUP` [here](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/VLOOKUP-function-0bbc8083-26fe-4963-8ab8-93a18ad188a1)

Note, this will not handle your "Max" without some further work. You could for example use this as input for a second formula something like:

```
=If([output] >= [Max], [Per LB Calculation], [output])
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not so clear what is the maximum price, but you can use the formula below  to calculate the `PriceFactor` per "LBS" range:

```
PriceFactor = WorksheetFunction.RoundUp((Kilo / 100), 0)
```

and then multiply `PriceFactor * 150` to get the `Result`.

**Code**

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim Kilo As Long, Result As Long
Dim PriceFactor As Double

Kilo = Range("A1").Value

PriceFactor = WorksheetFunction.RoundUp((Kilo / 100), 0)
Result = PriceFactor * 150

Range("B1").Value = Result

End Sub
```